# How to properly represent natural numbers less than n?

Tags: natural-numbers

What is the better representation for natural numbers $x$ less equal a number $n>0$ in a scientific paper?

1. $x \in \textbf{N}_{\le n}$ or
2. $x \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ or
3. $0 \lt x \le n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen the first one, but I'm sure someone has used it. The other two are definitely used. Conventions vary from one field to the next. The kind I would personally use is:

$$x\in[n].$$

Comment: Thank you. I'll definitely consider your suggestion. I don't remember where, but years ago I've seen the first one somewhere.

Comment: Yeah this is good but sometimes $x∈[n]$ could be also interpreted as $0\le x<n$ instead of $0<x\le n$. Go for the one you like the most, but remember to define it explicitely because it is not a standard notation